# Unable to ping specific IP address via WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping

I have a laptop which refuses to ping a specific IP address on my LAN at home.

I have a router, which connects a bunch of PCs, laptops, phones, etc. My router deals out the following IP addresses (among a lot of others):

- Desktop PC (windows 10 fall creators 1709) - 192.168.1.12 (WiFi)
- Laptop (windows 10 fall creators 1709) - 192.168.1.48 (WiFi)
- Raspberry pi (windows 10 IoT) - 192.168.1.28 (wired)

This results in the following :

1. From my desktop I can ping the raspberry pi.
2. From my laptop I can NOT ping the raspberry pi. (host unreachable)
3. From my laptop I CAN ping my desktop.

Now, when I disable WiFi on my laptop and wire it up via UTP, I am able to ping the raspberry pi.

I had the same issue at work, where I was not able to ping a Windows 7 embedded PC from my laptop. As soon as I got a wired connection I was able to ping the Windows 7 embedded PC. So there clearly is something wrong on my laptop *locally* with the WiFi configuration.

I tried things like :

- rebooting laptop
- flushing dns
- resetting winsock
- arp -R *

but nothing seems to help a thing.

Help is greatly appreciated!

PS: No idea if it's a coincidence, but the cases where my laptop seems to fail pinging to another PC, in both cases it was "a windows embedded" version. At work it was Windows Embedded Standard 7. At home it was Windows IoT. Maybe it's unrelated but maybe it's worth mentioning

UPDATE:

tracert also times out, but it DOES seems to be able to find out its computer name 'minwinpc' (??)

C:\Users\bp>tracert 192.168.1.28

```
Tracing route to minwinpc [192.168.1.28]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

UPDATE 2:

I tried a bit more, check this out! I am NOT able to ping 192.168.1.28 from my laptop. BUT, when I add `-a` it does resolve the computer name, while it still refuses to respond to ping on IP address. Then afterwards, I ping on its computer name, and it replies on ip6! When I then try to ping the computer name on ip4 it again times out... See below:

#### pinging IP addres

```
C:\SWSetup\SP82384\Win7Plus\Win64\Install>ping 192.168.1.28

Pinging 192.168.1.28 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

#### Pinging IP address with `-a` option

```
C:\SWSetup\SP82384\Win7Plus\Win64\Install>ping -a 192.168.1.28

Pinging minwinpc [192.168.1.28] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

#### Pinging the computer name, replies on ip6 ###

```
C:\SWSetup\SP82384\Win7Plus\Win64\Install>ping minwinpc

Pinging minwinpc [fe80::8d8f:feab:26d1:bf8a%39] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::8d8f:feab:26d1:bf8a%39: time=297ms
Reply from fe80::8d8f:feab:26d1:bf8a%39: time=2ms
Reply from fe80::8d8f:feab:26d1:bf8a%39: time=7ms
```

#### Attempting to ping computer name on ip4 again ###

```
C:\SWSetup\SP82384\Win7Plus\Win64\Install>ping minwinpc -4

Pinging minwinpc [192.168.1.28] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

Again, just for completeness, from my desktop PC (connected via WiFi, same SSID) I am able to ping the IP address on both ip4 and ip6

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the wifi drivers?  Seems like you've done most of the other standard troubleshooting of the Wifi device, but may have left this one out.

Comment: Check if your router is using wireless isolation ....

Comment: Will try / check both suggestions tomorrow! Thx

Comment: @DavidPostill Router is not set in 'set AP in wireless isolation'. PS; my desktop is also using the same WiFi (same SSID) and can ping 192.168.1.28

Comment: @AllenHoward done that too, still not able to ping 192.168.1.28 from my laptop...

Comment: @both please see update2 if you have ideas please do share!

Comment: Okay, one other question-- Are you statically assigning IPs or are you using DHCP?

Comment: @AllenHoward DHCP yes, please see answer below. Problem solved, not really an answer to what was wrong and how I got there though... but thx for helping out !

Comment: @bas where is the answer?

Comment: @srh I deleted the answer since it was incorrect. I found the issue after all though... my access point was misconfigured. it was "bridging" my wifi connection iso acting as a normal wireless access point.